# iOS Core Plot : Difference between CPPlot and CPTPlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

Could anyone explain what is the difference between CPPlot and CPTPlot. I am currently using CPTPlot.

Are all the features in CPPlot available even in CPTPlot?

How do I change my code from using CPTPlot to CPPlot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Core Plot first started, it used "CP" as the class prefix. This caused a conflict with a private framework that Apple introduced with Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6). We changed the class prefix to "CPT" to eliminate the name space conflict. See [issue 85](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=85) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC CPPLot was the old name for this class some time ago. No need to switch, just continue to use CPTPlot.